# Is there a way to bind a property to a child component and use it in a method in the child component?

Tags: angular

I have a property binded into a child component and I want to use that property as a value in a method in the child component.

I got the child component to display the property (estate.name) in the template, but I was getting a console error that the "id" property is undefined in the getEstateBlocks() method in the child component.

This is the template of the parent component:

```
<h3>Managed Estates</h3>
<div>
  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let estate of estates" (click)="onSelectEstate(estate)">
    <div>
      <h4>{{estate.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<app-estate-blocks [estate]="selectedEstate"></app-estate-blocks>
```

this is the onSelectEstate() method in the parent component:

```
onSelectEstate(estate: Estate) {
    this.selectedEstate = estate;
  }
```

This is the child component template:

```
<div *ngIf="estate">
  <h2>Blocks in {{estate.name}}</h2>
<ul >
  <li *ngFor="let block of blocks">
    <a >
      <span>BLOCK</span> {{block.blockName | uppercase}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the code in the child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-estate-blocks',
  templateUrl: './estate-blocks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./estate-blocks.component.css']
})
export class EstateBlocksComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() estate: Estate;
  blocks: Block[];

  constructor(private estateService: EstatesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBlocks();
  }

  getBlocks() {
    return this.estateService.getEstateBlocks(this.estate.id)
      .subscribe(blocks => this.blocks = blocks);
  }
```

I expected the blocks of a selected estate to be displayed below the estate list when an estate is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you're using that property before setting it

Here, you're using `this.estate`, but, because this is inside an `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, it will be triggered the moment you write `<app-estate-blocks>` inside your HTML

```
// this will get instantly executed
ngOnInit() {
    this.getBlocks();
}
```

avoiding your `estate-block` component to render before setting `selectedEstate`  should solve this issue

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedEstate">
    <app-estate-blocks [estate]="selectedEstate"></app-estate-blocks>
</ng-container>
```